# How to iterate over all optional arguments and related values?

Tags: python, for-loop, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am new to Python and I would like to implement a `script.py` so to handle the following command

```
python script.py --opt value1 --opt value2 --opt value3 ... --opt valueN
```

and to print all `--opt` values, like this:

```
value1
value2
value3
...
valueN
```

How can I make that?

---

My script is:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--opt", help="option description")
args = parser.parse_args()

for arg_opt in args.opt:
    print(arg_opt)
```

I tried to play with the `for` loop to iterate over the `--opt` value but without success: running the above code will output just the last `--opt` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [action](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action) argument to `append`:

> 'append' - This stores a list, and appends each argument value to the
>   list. This is useful to allow an option to be specified multiple
>   times.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--opt", action='append')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.opt)
```

Demo:

```
$ python test_argparse.py --opt value1 --opt value2 --opt value3
['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
```

Comment: And if in the same script I would like to handle both cases the one in the question with `python script.py --opt value1 --opt value2 --opt value3 ... --opt valueN` (that you correctly answered) and the one with `python script.py --opt value1 value2 value3 ... valueN`? That is, in the last case I would like to support multiple values with one or more `--opt`. Is it possible?

Comment: @Backo specifying `nargs='*'` should help in this case.

Comment: `nargs='*'` makes almost what I am looking for but it generates "nested" arrays: when I run `python script.py --opt value1 value2 --opt value3 --opt valueN` then it outputs `[['value1', 'value2'], ['value3'], ['valueN']]`. It should be `['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'valueN']`.

Comment: @Backo well, as far as I understand, if you want to support both cases - you need to handle the nested output. Just flatten the list.